# Docker error when re-using dockerfile to create another image : exec format error

Tags: python, windows, docker, dockerfile

I am pretty new to Docker and I am getting an error that I cannot solve.

I have two programs that I want to containerize, and both program need the exact same environment. I built a dockerfile **that works perfectly fine** for the first program a few weeks ago, and now I am trying to create another image for the second program, using the same dockerfile.

For the first program, everything works (building + running).

For the second program, the build finishes successfully, however when I try to launch it, the container launches but I directly get the error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

Now I've read on a few other posts that this is often related to a wrong target architecture, but how could this be the case since I am using this dockerfile for another program that works just fine on the same machine ?

Here's the dockerfile :

```
# load python 3.8 dependencies using slim debian 10 image.
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# build variables.
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

# install Microsoft SQL Server requirements.
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl gcc g++ gnupg unixodbc-dev

# Add SQL Server ODBC Driver 17 for Ubuntu 18.04
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
  && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/10/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
  && apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends --allow-unauthenticated msodbcsql17 mssql-tools \
  && echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile \
  && echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc

# upgrade pip and install requirements.
COPY /requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

# clean the install.
RUN apt-get -y clean

# copy all files to /app directory and move into directory.
COPY src/ /app
WORKDIR /app

CMD [ "python", "./handler.py" ]
```

I tried also reformatting the python file in LF, no difference.

Comment: are you building and running the image on the same machine? With the same architecture?

Comment: Yes, same machine, same OS, same everything.